# OK to leave open combustion air pipe in crawlspace sucking air from crawlspace? I like in Alaska and we have had a lot of snow blocking outside vent

Tags: hvac, safety, moisture, crawlspace, venting

We recently had an unusual snowstorm that completely covered the open combustion air pipe that is vented at almost ground level to the outside.  This caused the HVAC to shut down.  We are worried about being able to keep this vent open during the rest of this winter.  Just had an HVAC man out who cut the connection to the outside and said for the rest of this winter our HVAC would suck air from the crawl space instead.  He will reconnect to the outside air on his next service next summer.  What does this patch mean and should I have allowed it?

Comment: Is your crawlspace vented?

Comment: Most fuel heating devices need fresh air to work/burn.  In a well sealed(no cold drafts from outside) house the furnace needs to get air from somewhere, hopefully not the same air you need to breath/live, so outside vents.  A drafty house has less need for a vent.

Comment: That's a good question and one I can't answer.  This house was built in 2012 and is a five-star rated home so I'm thinking it is pretty tight.  Our HOA conducts crawlspace inspections each year, mostly checking for moisture as I understand it.  It is, I think, a well sealed area with visqueen covering the ground area and is quite clean down there.  There is also an air exchange system in the house in which outside air is exchanged for inside air.